# How Do I Edit Input Value In Javascript?

Tags: javascript, input

I am trying to edit the following input form to change the maxlength value.

```
<div id="chat-input">
    <form class="chat-input-form" onsubmit="return false">
        <input id="chat-input-field" value="" placeholder="Click here to join the conversation" maxlength="256" type="text">
    </form>
</div>
```

Say I want to change the maxlength of the input to 300, how would I go about doing this client side?
I know I can use inspect element, but I am trying to do it with a JavaScript file.

Comment: Isn't it just `document.getElementById('chat-input-field').maxLength = xxx;` ?

Comment: This was the first thing I tried, but I am still limited to 256.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty simple:

```
document.getElementById('chat-input-field').maxLength = 300
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9cjh4/).

Don't forget to wrap the code inside of a document ready function. Something like this should do it, but stick to jQuery [$(document).ready()](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) if you want to support stone age browsers too.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
   document.getElementById('chat-input-field').maxLength = 300
});
```

---

> I don't think I would need to add the DOMContentLoaded because the
>   javascript file I am using is only added after the website is finished
>   loading.

Then try this.

```
console.log(document.getElementById('chat-input-field'));

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
   console.log(document.getElementById('chat-input-field').maxLength);
});
```

Expected result in console:

> null
>
> 256

Comment: I don't think I would need to add the DOMContentLoaded because the javascript file I am using is only added after the website is finished loading.

Comment: As far as I know, the only difference between the working JSfiddle and your test is the `onLoad` statement. This might be suggesting you something.

Comment: Ok I was wrong, the DOMContentLoaded does make it work. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Ok it was working for a minute when I first tried it, but now I can't get it to work at all. I even tried doing the console log commands, but instead off undefined and 256, I get [object HTMLInputElement] which gives me all this information I do not need. Did I miss a step this time? I figured all I needed to use to run it would be document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
   document.getElementById('chat-input-field').maxLength = 300;
}); Is that wrong?

Comment: yes, that's all you need. Try to clear the browser cache and refresh the page.